# How to apply two CCActions to two different CCSprites and run them in the same time on one CCLayer?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

Actually the question is in the title. Anyway I would like to repeat it:
**Question:** How I could apply two different CCActions to two different CCSprites and run them in the same time on one CCLayer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why cannot you just create two actions and run them on needed sprites in one method? actually I cannot see any need of this question as it contains answer inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CCLayer has nothing to do with that. You just send the runAction message with the action one after another to have the actions start running at the same time:

```
id action1 = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:1];
[sprite1 runAction:action1];

id action2 = [CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:1];
[sprite2 runAction:action2];
```

Comment: Thanks! That was really stupid question. One more thing, if I had one action, and I want to apply it to two different sprites and to run them in the same time, could I do that? I tried, but only one sprite is moving.

Comment: no, you cannot run action several times and need to recreate it each time

Comment: Ok, thaks! So to increase performance I need to use CCAnimationCache, as I know. Thanks, it helped me a lot.)